# How to include column values as null even when condition is not met?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Write a query to show ALL building names, their metering company name and meter type for all buildings that do not have postpaid meters.

The image 1 is the result that I should get and image 2 is the results that i am getting:

[image: Results should be]

[image]

```
USE Ultimate_DataBase
GO

SELECT [Bld_Name], [Elec_company_name], [Mtype_Name]
FROM [dbo].[Metering_Company] A
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Metering_Type] D
ON A.[MType_ID]= D.MType_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Building_metering] B
ON A.[Elec_ID]= B.[Elec_ID]
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Building] C
ON C.[Bld_ID]= B.[Bld_ID]
WHERE [Mtype_Name] != 'POSTPAID'
```

Comment: You have to remove the where condition to get all results.

Comment: Please don't use images - use formatted text.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu The OP is not asking how to get all results, they're asking why NULLS are being excluded when a WHERE clause is applied

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `WHERE` logic to the corresponding `ON` clause:

```
SELECT [Bld_Name], [Elec_company_name], [Mtype_Name]
FROM [dbo].[Metering_Company] A
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Metering_Type] D
    ON A.[MType_ID]= D.MType_ID AND
       [Mtype_Name] != 'POSTPAID'              -- change is here
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Building_metering] B
    ON A.[Elec_ID]= B.[Elec_ID]
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Building] C
    ON C.[Bld_ID]= B.[Bld_ID];
```

Note: Please add aliases to your select clause.  They are not *mandatory*, assuming no two tables ever have columns by the same name, but just having aliases would have made your question easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

`FULL JOIN` isn't seem necessary -- in fact `FULL JOIN` is almost never needed, and especially not for routine `JOIN`s in a well-structured database.

The structure of the question suggests `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM dbo.Building b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.Building_metering bm JOIN
                       dbo.Metering_Company mc
                       ON bm.Elec_ID = mc.Elec_ID JOIN
                       dbo.Metering_Type mt
                       ON mt.MType_ID = mc.MType_ID
                  WHERE bm.Bld_ID = b.Bld_ID AND mt.Mtype_Name = 'POSTPAID' 
                 );
```

You can also express this as a `LEFT JOIN` and filtering:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM dbo.Building b LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Building_metering bm 
     ON bm.Bld_ID = b.Bld_ID LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Metering_Company mc
     ON bm.Elec_ID = mc.Elec_ID LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Metering_Type mt
     ON mt.MType_ID = mc.MType_ID AND
        mt.Mtype_Name = 'POSTPAID' 
WHERE mt.MType_ID IS NULL;
```

This allows you to select columns from any of the tables.

Notes:

- `FULL JOIN` is almost never needed.
- Use meaningful table aliases!  Arbitrary letters mean nothing.  Use table abbreviations.
- Escaping column and table names with square braces just makes code harder to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE Ultimate_DataBase
GO

SELECT [Bld_Name], [Elec_company_name], [Mtype_Name]
FROM [dbo].[Metering_Company] A
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Metering_Type] D
ON A.[MType_ID]= D.MType_ID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Building_metering] B
ON A.[Elec_ID]= B.[Elec_ID]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Building] C
ON C.[Bld_ID]= B.[Bld_ID]
```

Use this